# How to populate several item UDF fields into one header UDF field?

Tags: user-defined-functions, sapb1

I have created 5 UDF fields in item master using SAP Business One as you can see in the below picture:

[image: SAP Business One - Item Master Data]

Now I want to fetch those 5 UDF value in Bill of material (BOM)'s header level UDF field 'Drawing no' as you can see in the below picture:

[image: SAP Business One - Bill of Material]

As of now only one value is coming from list of 5 UDF fields i.e 'abc'  as you can see in the second picture.

Could you please help me to populate all 5 UDF field in 'Drawing no' in picture 2?

Comment: How is the question related to [tag:flash-media-server]?

Comment: No -  it is related to  SAP Business One

Answer (score 1):

Using a User Defined Query you should be able to Concatenate your multiple fields

Choose " Search in Existing User-Defined Values According to Saved Query "
[image: Formatted Search Option]

The Query Should look similar to this:

```
SELECT T0.[myUdf1] + T0.[myUdf2]  FROM OITM T0 WHERE T0.[ItemCode] = $[$4.0.0]
```